# Hyper-V Networking

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

Anyone tried to setup the guest OS in Hyper-V having 2 Network adapter and use at the same time? like 1 is for Public and 1 for Private.

Because the host OS have 2 NIC, 1 for Private LAN and 1 for Public, so trying to do the same with the guest OS.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Create two virtual network switches on the host OS and select the check box "Allow management OS to share this network adapter".
Then use the same inside the VM